# Javascript Validation in Master Page and Content Place Holder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

I'm using asp.net. I have a login form in Master page. I have written Javascript validation function for this in Master Page.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUsername"/></td>
        <td>Password:></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword"/></td>
        <td>Username:></td>
        <td><asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also I am having Send Email form in Content Place Holder. I have written Javascript validation function for this in Content Place Holder.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>To:></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtTo"/></td>
        <td>Password:></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtEmail"/></td>
        <td>Username:></td>
        <td><asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSend" Text="Send"/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

My Issue is when I click on the btnSend button, the validations of Login form are occurring?

**Edited:**
*Solution:*
The problem is I am using the same validation function name for both the Master Page and Content Place Holder. I changed the Validation function name in the Master Page and that resolved the issue

Comment: can you please show your javascript function ?

Comment: I think you need to place the "Login section" & the "Send email section" in 2 different panels and also consider using Validation groups http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx along with asp.net validation controls..

Answer (score 0):

If you have server side validations you can disable them in your javascript function as shown below:

```
ValidatorEnable("reqValId", false);
```

To Enable:

```
ValidatorEnable("reqValId", true);
```